# What is the difference between the class attribute schedule and the object attribute data of celery.beat.Scheduler in Celery?

Tags: celery, scheduler

In Celery(v5.3.6), the celery.beat.Scheduler class has a class attribute schedule and an object attribute data, and their values seem to be the same.In the following part of the code, the class attribute `schedule` and the object attribute `data` are linked using the `property()` method. What's the purpose of this? Will it not cause confusion to use the `Scheduler` class and the `Scheduler()` object successively to assign values and query the `schedule` attribute?
code show as below:

```
class Scheduler:
    """Scheduler for periodic tasks.

    ...

    Arguments:
        schedule (~celery.schedules.schedule): see :attr:`schedule`.
        max_interval (int): see :attr:`max_interval`.
        lazy (bool): Don't set up the schedule.
    """

    Entry = ScheduleEntry

    #: The schedule dict/shelve.
    schedule = None

    #: Maximum time to sleep between re-checking the schedule.
    max_interval = DEFAULT_MAX_INTERVAL

    ...

    def __init__(self, app, schedule=None, max_interval=None,
                 Producer=None, lazy=False, sync_every_tasks=None, **kwargs):
        self.app = app
        self.data = maybe_evaluate({} if schedule is None else schedule)
        
        ...

    ...


    def get_schedule(self):
        return self.data

    def set_schedule(self, schedule):
        self.data = schedule
    schedule = property(get_schedule, set_schedule)
```

I'm reading the source code, and I don't feel confused after reading this part. I hope someone can help me answer this part of the confusion?